# reorganizing the pages of a PDF in a given (wicked) Sequence – an attempt with PyPDF2

Tags: sequence, pypdf, reorganize

I have a PDF-document with **a given page order** 
(let’s say 1 is page 1 and 2 is page2)

so at the beginning the page order is normal,

*1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9....*

but now I need to rearrange the pages in the PDF-documen in a wicked way to print it --> I have to chage the sequence of pages **to the necessary sequence**:

*1,2,3, 7,8,9, 13,14,15, 4,5,6 ,10,11,12, 16,17,18*

and then the same with pages *19* to *36* 
and then again from *37* to *54*

I tried it with the Python package PyPDF2 and managed to have every page of the *example.pdf* ouputed as *example_page-*  * *.pdf*, so that page 1 is now called *example_page-1.pdf*  and page 65 is called *example_page-65.pdf*.

But how can i get the documents to be merged in the *necessary sequence*?

My attempt was with the following manipulations to the code presented by DZone (https://dzone.com/articles/splitting-and-merging-pdfs-with-python):

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter

def pdf_splitter(path):

fname = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]



pdf = PdfFileReader(path)

for page in range(pdf.getNumPages()):

    pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()

    pdf_writer.addPage(pdf.getPage(page))



    output_filename = '{}_page_{}.pdf'.format(

        fname, page+1)



    with open(output_filename, 'wb') as out:

        pdf_writer.write(out)



    print('Created: {}'.format(output_filename))



if __name__ == '__main__':

path = '/Users/timmy/Desktop/Print_Order_Problem/THE_ORDERED.pdf'

pdf_splitter(path)
```

merging back together

```
import glob

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger



def merger(output_path, input_paths):
    pdf_merger = PdfFileMerger()
    file_handles = []

    for path in input_paths:
        pdf_merger.append(path)

    with open(output_path, 'wb') as fileobj:
        pdf_merger.write(fileobj)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    paths = glob.glob('THE_ORDERED_page_*.pdf')

    paths.replace()
    paths.sort()

    merger('pdf_merger1.pdf', paths)
```

I hope to be able to merge the PDFs in the given order. I know that the `paths.sort()` step has to be altered.

I think it's a great problem and I am astonished how complex and exciting this is! Any help is greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 2):

I would not distract you from your fine PyPDF2 experiment. Your plan sounds good. However, for information, on an open-source platform, the non-Python utility `pdftk` can reorder pages.

Once the utility `pdftk` is installed, you can invoke it from the command line approximately like this:

```
pdftk in.pdf cat 1 2 3 7 8 9 13 14 15 4 5 6 10 11 12 16 17 18 output out.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, @thb!

I already tried it by just using cat but as I needed to split the document anyway with python, why not got with an all python handicraft. 

I also tried your suggestion with pdftk, apparently mac doesn't accept the opensource utility which is kind of a typical mac problem. Do you have a suggestion how to run it on simple linux commands?

Comment: I thought about creating a tulip for the **necessary sequence** so I could iterate over it and for a given _example_page-**N**.pdf_  it would replace **N** by the value of the tulip at the corresponding position (**N**-1) (because it starts with 0).